# Update object in Angular Javascript application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following data

```
{
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "serviceLocation": {
        "verified": true,
        "formattedAddress": "2110 El Pinto Rd, Sullivan City, TX 78595",
        "address1": "2110 El Pinto Rd",
        "city": "Sullivan City",
        "state": "TX",
        "zip": "78595"
      },
      "additionalLocations": [],
      "services": {
        "electric": {
          "selectedProgramId": null,
          "utilityAndProgram": null,
          "serviceProvider": null
        },
        "naturalGas": {
          "selectedProgramId": null,
          "utilityAndProgram": null,
          "serviceProvider": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "authorizedParty": {
    "firstName": "sdfsad",
    "lastName": "asdgfdsaf",
    "phone": "(222) 222-2222"
  },
  "contactPreference": "phone",
  "signature": null,
  "isNew": false
}
```

I want to change the property `address1`

So I created a bit of code but the problem is that it wipes out all my other properties when I do this

```
 var newAddress = [{
    "serviceLocation":{
      "address1": orderNew + " apt 335" 
    }
  }];

 order.lineItems[0].serviceLocation = newAddress[0].serviceLocation;
```

I was trying to then do something like this

```
  var newOrder = [{
     "serviceLocation": {
        ".address1": orderNew + " apt 335" 
     }
  }];

 orders.lineItems.serviceLocation[0].address1; =newOrder[0].serviceLocation['.address1'];
```

Having problems with that though.

Comment: why not just `order.lineItems[0].serviceLocation.address1 = orderNew + " apt 335";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, if we were to store that data into an object like so

```
var obj = {
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "serviceLocation": {
        "verified": true,
        "formattedAddress": "2110 El Pinto Rd, Sullivan City, TX 78595",
        "address1": "2110 El Pinto Rd",
        "city": "Sullivan City",
        "state": "TX",
        "zip": "78595"
      },
      "additionalLocations": [],
      "services": {
        "electric": {
          "selectedProgramId": null,
          "utilityAndProgram": null,
          "serviceProvider": null
        },
        "naturalGas": {
          "selectedProgramId": null,
          "utilityAndProgram": null,
          "serviceProvider": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "authorizedParty": {
    "firstName": "sdfsad",
    "lastName": "asdgfdsaf",
    "phone": "(222) 222-2222"
  },
  "contactPreference": "phone",
  "signature": null,
  "isNew": false
}
```

the way to change `address1` will be like so:

```
a.lineItems[0].serviceLocation.address1 = 'new value';
```

is this what you were looking for?

Keep me posted!